# How to use mysql_insert_id with a junction table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysql-insert-id, junction

I have a form and three tables: `customer`, `phone_number`, and `junction` (to create a many-to-many relationship).

I need the form to populate all three tables using the newly created auto-incremented ids from the `customer` and `phone number` tables to populate the `customer_id` and `phone_id` columns in the `junction` table.

I came up with the following, which will insert the newly created id from the `customer` table into the `junction` table, but I can't figure out how to get the phone number to do the same thing.

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s)",
GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text"));
$result = mysql_query();
$insertID = mysql_insert_id();

$query = "INSERT INTO junction (customer_id) VALUES ($insertID)";
mysql_select_db($database_hh, $hh);
$result = mysql_query($query, $hh) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Where is your `phone_number` INSERT query? It should basically go; 1) Insert into `customer`, get ID (`$customerId`). 2) Insert into `phone_number`, get ID (`$phoneId`). 3) Insert both IDs into `junction`

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudo code for you:

```php
//Insert a customer
$query = "INSERT INTO `customer` ..."
...
//Get the newly inserted customer's ID
$customer_id = mysqli_insert_id();

//Insert a phone
$query = "INSERT INTO `phone` ..."
...
//Get the newly inserted phone's ID
$phone_id = mysqli_insert_id();
...
//Insert them in the junction table
$query = "INSERT INTO `junction` (customer_id, phone_id) VALUES ($customer_id, $phone_id)"
```

And since you are using `mysql_*` here is the comment that you might see a lot here at StackOveflow:

> Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Yeah, I just left the phone query out of my example because it didn't work.

Comment: That totally makes sense and is so much simpler than the Frankenstein code I came up with. All my books, with their dense examples, had me over-thinking it. I've been stuck on this for months, so I appreciate the help, Phil. I feel like I can actually make some progress now.